# Retrieving single and multiple objects via GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm less than a couple of weeks into using Apollo and GraphQL, and I'd like to retrieve multiple objects via GraphQL, but it won't allow me to.

With the query as:

```
const GET_ALL_PURCHASES_QUERY = (statusOfPurchase) => {
  return gql`
  query {
    getAllPurchases(statusOfPurchase: "${statusOfPurchase}") {
      id
      customerInformation {
        customerName
        customerEmailAddress
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`
}
```

... and in the schema:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootQueryType',
  fields: {
    getAllPurchases: {
      type: PurchaseType,
      args: {
        statusOfPurchase: {
          type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return PurchasesModel.schemaForPurchases.find({
          statusOfPurchase: args.statusOfPurchase
        }).limit(10)
          .then(purchases => {
            console.log('Schema:getAllPurchases()', purchases)
            return purchases
          })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Result in Node via the Terminal is:

```
Schema:getAllPurchases() [
  {
    _id: 60351a691d3e5a70d63eb13e,
    customerInformation: [ [Object] ],
    statusOfPurchase: 'new',
    createdAt: 2021-02-23T15:08:25.230Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-02-23T15:08:25.230Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60351b966de111716f2d8a6d,
    customerInformation: [ [Object] ],
    statusOfPurchase: 'new',
    createdAt: 2021-02-23T15:13:26.552Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-02-23T15:13:26.552Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Correct.

But in the application within Chrome, it's a single object with null as the value of each field.

With the query as:

```
const GET_ALL_PURCHASES_QUERY = () => {
  return gql`
  query {
    getAllPurchases {
      id
      customerInformation {
        customerName
        customerEmailAddress
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`
}
```

... and with the appropriate changes to the schema, the result is the same as before, where I see two objects in Node but a failed single object in Chrome.

If I change: `return purchases` to: `return purchases[0]` I see the first object in Chrome with the correct values.

How am I supposed to return more than one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type for the `getAllPurchases` field is set to `PurchaseType` in the schema. You want to use `new GraphQLList(PurchaseType)` to have the return type be a list of purchases. That's why when you try to use the schema, it returns null if the types are bad, but correctly returns a purchase if you do return a single element.

See [the graphql docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqllist) for an example of this.

Comment: Alex, much appreciated.